# How to load ScrollView with PFImageView

Tags: ios, scrollview, parse-platform, horizontalscrollview, detailview

Does anyone know how to load images (plural) inside a ScrollView using PFImageView.. I manage to load only 1 image but can't make a the next PFImageview.

Remember these images are being downloaded by Parse.com and the objects have been passed through a cell segue to a DetailView.

The code to load images in a PFImageView is:

```
    look1.file = bellezaView.image_1;
    [look1 loadInBackground];
```

That is one image, how would I load the next one?

I'd really appreciate any help.. Have been stuck at this for a week already! Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain how you want it to work? How is the use workflow?

Comment: Of course! (I want a Horizontal ScrollView) so my first view is a PFQueryTable, after the user clicks on a cell you are segued to a DetailView. In this Detailview there is a ScrollView and in the ScrollView there is a PFImageView. I get all the information set and good for 1 image, but don't know how to load a second PFImageView... I can't find any examples or tutorial that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UICollectionView for this. Here is a thorough tutorial: http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial

Another option is to use UIPageViewController, where each photo is in its own page. I use this for a photo browser in one of my apps. Here is a nice tutorial for it:
http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

You can also try a library called iCarousel: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: Thanks!! So there is no way I could do it the way I'm trying to? If not I'll just go along with the PageViewController.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you were originally thinking. A scroll view with lots of PFImageViews scrolling horizontally?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to adapt this code setup in a PFImageView in a ScrollView:
    'UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
    CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d", i+1]];'
Here is my code:
  'PFImageView *lookView = [[PFImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
   CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
   lookView.file = bellezaView.image_1,i+1;'
But I get an Error expression "result unused"

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in your other question. Do you have a code example where a scroll view shows multiple UIImageView horizontally?

Comment: Yup, this is the example I've been following:     http://danielbeard.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/adding-a-uiscrollview-to-a-uiview-ios/

Comment: Everything works perfectly.. but my Image is being repeated for how every many views I have because I cannot set the stringFormat or the i+1 expression. Don't know how... Maybe you have an idea? :)

Comment: I think I figured it out.. I have an answer in the other question.. Now I'm trying to figure out how to show the information of every image after clicking a button (same in all PFImageViews).. Maybe I'm better of with the PageController!! Thanks for you time!